# how to keep login while automating a website

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, flask, multiprocessing

I'm trying to automate a website using python and selenium. I've define functions to login into the website and add users to the website. and deploy it in Heroku with the help of flask.

```
def login():
    '''login process here'''

def add_user():
    '''adding user process here'''
```

The website is automatically logout after 10 minutes. But if I click on a button on the website or refresh the page it reset the time (like it will take another 10 minutes to logout). So what I'm trying to is I want to click on that button for every 9 minutes or refresh after every 9 minutes mean while user should be able to use the function `add_user()`.

I've tried with multi threading and multi processing still I couldn't find a solution, Anyone can help me?

Comment: did you tried to  create another thread to perform the refresh each 9 minutes?

Comment: @Razvan i don't know how to do it? If you can tell me it will be a big help